# Multiple Open and Close Time array validation in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have array of open time and close time.

The inputs look like this:

```
 <input type="text" name="time[1][open]">
 <input type="text" name="time[1][close]">
 <input type="text" name="time[x][open]">
 <input type="text" name="time[x][close]">
```

This is a dump from `dd($request->all())`

```
array:2 [
  "days" => array:2 [
    0 => "1" // Mon
    1 => "2" // Tue
  ]
  "time" => array:2 [
    1 => array:2 [
      "open" => "09:00"
      "close" => "11:30"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [
      "open" => "16:00"
      "close" => "21:00"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Using Laravel Request Validation - how do loop through between open and close time to validate to make sure it does not overlap of existing record in mysql database?  For example, we may have Open:14:00 - Close:19:00 in the database but user have a requested of `"open" => "16:00"` and `"close" => "21:00"` - so the validation should not passed.

Update:

Example result in the `times` table, a day can have multiple open/close times.

```
id   |   day    |   open_time  |   close_time
-----------------------------------------------
1    |    1     |   13:30:00   |    15:00:00
2    |    2     |   16:30:00   |    20:00:00
3    |    3     |   09:30:00   |    14:30:00
4    |    3     |   18:00:00   |    22:00:00
-----------------------------------------------
```

You can see there is overlapping from `times.id=2` (16:30:00 - 20:00:00) and user request `"open" => "16:00"` and `"close" => "21:00"`. Validation should not passed.

Comment: If you can describe the "check", write validator yourself :), if you need detailed guidance on how, just make bump here.

Comment: @Kyslik I need detailed guidance on how to loop each day (`days` field) and then do validation of `time` array. It need to check through database.

Comment: Could you provide migration for table in question? Do you have an idea how to make check yourself (don't worry about "validator code") just try to write pseudo code, lets say you have an input like you demonstrated and also you have data already loaded from database, are you able to write function that returns true / false?

Comment: @Kyslik I have updated the question - don't worry about the time comparing, I can do that myself. Question is more going through the loop of user request and then check through the database.

Comment: Do you want to write a reusable validation rule, or just "simply" check the request (as you mention).

Comment: I like to use laravel validation rule

Comment: @Kyslik php artisan make:request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128299/discussion-between-kyslik-and-ill-be-back).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is not a complete answer but it might help OP. I still do not understand relation between days / time etc. this is boilerplate without logic that needs to be implemented

---

firstly make new provider (for custom validation rules)

```
$ php artisan make:provider ValidatorServiceProvider
```

and register it in config/app.php

```
    ...
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\ValidatorServiceProvider::class,
    ...
```

Make new folder/file for new validation rule:

```
$ mkdir ./app/Validators
$ touch ./app/Validators/OverlappingTimeValidator.php
```

And put some code inside new Validator rule (can not make out the logic since I do not understand problem fully, perhaps I lack language skill to understand it)

```
<?php

namespace App\Validators;

class OverlappingTimeValidator
{
    public function validate($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
    {
        //make sure you have valid time format (for each time[])
        //make sure open < close for each pair
        //compare each set of open-close times with each other
        //connect to database and get all required data from $parameters[0] table
        //to connect to database and get data use \DB::table($parameters[0])->get(); follow this https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#retrieving-results
        //array_get($validator->getData(), $parameters[1], null); // gives you days user picked or null
        dd($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator);
        return false; //in case validation fails
        return true; //in case validation passes
    }
}
```

run `$ composer dump-autoload` so new file is auto-loaded

register validation rule in ValidatorServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('overlapping_time', 'App\Validators\OverlappingTimeValidator@validate');
}
```

And finally rules in *Request should look like:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'time' => 'overlapping_time:table_name,days'
    ];
}
```

You may use `'time.*'` and validation will run against each time separately which you may not want! So use `'time'` and make validation on whole array of times.

> As I understand days is relevant attribute in validating time, therefore I added it as parameter, but you can change it. Please see what `dd()` in `OverlappingTimeValidator@validate` outputs.

In order to add error message open up `./resources/lang/en/validation.php` and add (near bottom, really does not matter):

```
'overlapping_time' => 'The :attribute...',
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like

```
 'time.*.open' => 'required',
 'time.*.close' => 'after:time.*.open',
```

Refer this link

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#validating-arrays

Comment: That does not cover checking between open time and close time in the database - to make sure it does not overlap.